# How to create multi-window macOS menu bar app using NSPopOverControllers

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit

I'm making a simple macOS menu bar app with NSTable view and detail screen. I was able to show table view screen using NSPopOverController. When user clicks on the item it should show a detail screen. I have implemented click action of NSTableView cell and present the detail screen as NSPopover on top of the current screen.

```
@objc func didSelectRow(){
    guard let vc = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateController(withIdentifier: "DetailVC") as? NSViewController else{return }
    let popOverView = NSPopover()
    popOverView.contentViewController = vc
    popOverView.behavior = .applicationDefined
    popOverView.show(relativeTo: statusItem.button!.bounds, of: statusItem.button!, preferredEdge: .maxY)

}
```

Here is my detail VC which closes the presented popover window when back button is pressed

```
class DetailVC: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var wordLbl: NSTextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var readingLbl: NSTextField!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
    }
    
    @IBAction func backBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    
        self.view.window?.close()
        
    }
}
```

When I run the app and select an item in NSTableView it shows the detail window. When I press back button in detail window it closes it. Then when I select another element from the NSTableView it does not show the detail screen again.

Comment: multi-window macOS menu bar app using NSPopOverControllers with `NSTable View` isn't simple. What is `NSPopOverController`?

Comment: Tip: don't use `NSPopover` and `self.view.window?`. Present and dismiss the view controller instead.